# Can't return float value from python to HTML

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to return prices from 36 products on an API, the prices are float values.
Here is the products I am trying to take values from: https://pastebin.com/4k1rif6h
(this could be needed if you need to get access to the API, check below)

When I am trying to return the float values to my HTML I am getting an error: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable (I have read the thread about that issue, but it didn't help me).

here is my python code:

```
@app.route('/bresell')
def reSell():
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[tell me if key will be needed for helping]').json()

    for x in npc_products:
        sellPriceNPC = f["products"][x]["sell_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"]
    return render_template('resell.html', sellPriceNPC=sellPriceNPC)
```

and here is what I am doing on HTML:

```
<tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>temp</td>
        <td>temp</td>
        {% for sellFor in sellPriceNPC %}
        <td>{{ sellFor }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: It seems `sellPriceNPC` is a float and not a list, in your template for a trying to loop through  `sellPriceNPC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to iterate over `sellPriceNPC` (the `for sellFor in sellPriceNPC`), but it's not an iterable (it's not a list), since you're assigning each float value directly to it:

```
sellPriceNPC = f["products"][x]["sell_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"]
```

Instead you want to keep a list and append to that list:

```
sellPriceNPC = []

for x in npc_products:
    sellPriceNPC.append(f["products"][x]["sell_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"])

return render_template('resell.html', sellPriceNPC=sellPriceNPC)
```

That way you can properly iterate over the list and output each price by itself.